# How call function in For each loop?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a simple function to get data:

```
Function GetAppro(Current_Sheet As String)

   Dim myArray As Variant

   myArray = Worksheets(Current_Sheet).Range("A3:C6")

   GetAppro = myArray
End Function
```

And other funtion to get other data:

```
Function GetTabs()

Dim Get_Tabs_generated(2) As String

Get_Tabs_generated(0) = "AA"
Get_Tabs_generated(1) = "BB"
Get_Tabs_generated(2) = "CC"

 GetTabs = Get_Tabs_generated
End Function
```

In my final procedure i do:

```
Sub GenerateDB()

  Dim Appro() As String
  Dim Tabs() As String

  'Init
  Tabs = GetTabs() 

  For Each Tabs_item In Tabs
      Appro = GetAppro(Tabs_item.Value)
      MsgBox Appro(0, 0)
  Next Tabs_item

End Sub
```

Excel say me compile error Object required (Error 424). I am novice with functions

Comment: What line is the error? `myArray = Worksheets(Current_Sheet).Range("A3:C6")`?

Comment: also appro will be a base 1 array.  It will start at 1 not 0.

Comment: Your first function and the output are spelled different

Comment: line error is `MsgBox Appro(0, 0)`.

Comment: try `MsgBox Appro(1,1)`

Comment: @ScottCraner: I rectified but the error is same :(

Comment: You error is not on the line you suggested but the one above that.  Change it to `Appro = GetAppro(CStr(tabs_item))`  There is no value abject on an array item.

Comment: I commented 'MsgBox Appro(1,1) and the error is same so it's not MsgBox Appro(1,1) the problem. Excel doesn't say me error line. So i think the problem come from `Appro = GetAppro(Tabs_item.Value)`

Comment: Yes it's works now. Thanks to @ScottCraner. I forgot CStr() !!!!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
Do not forget CStr()

```
Sub GenerateDB()

  Dim Appro() As String
  Dim Tabs() As String

  'Init
  Tabs = GetTabs() 

  For Each Tabs_item In Tabs
      Appro = GetAppro(CStr(Tabs_item))
      MsgBox Appro(0, 0)
  Next Tabs_item

End Sub
```

Special thanks to @ScottCraner